# How to entering to URLs in Django?

Tags: python, django, web, web-deployment

Well I just started today working with the Django app but when I follow his tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_uQrJ0TkZlc&t=18317s at 5:20:20 The machine won't let me go to the URL of 127.0.0.1:8000/products/

```
    pyshop\urls.py 

from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('products/', include('products.urls'))

    products\urls.py

from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index),
    path('new', views.new)
]

    views.py

from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render


def index(request):
    return HttpResponse('Hello World')


def new(request):
    HttpResponse('New Products')
```

Comment: Do you add your app in the setting?

Comment: You're going to need to debug this. Try running `python manage.py show_urls` to get the application to list out all the loaded URLs.

Comment: How do I check if I add the app in the setting?
how do I debug?